# kendo grid databound is being recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have a kendoGrid with a dataBound function set.

Below is a sample of my code, inside the databound are some sets that update the UI view. This issue is that if I put a debugger on the second line (var pageData...) I can watch the .set trigger the dataBound function again. I would assume that the function should run once, and that .sets would not retrigger it.

If you have any idea what I am doing wrong, please help. Thanks

```
function() {
    var pageData = grid.dataSource.data();
    $.each(pageData, function(index, row){
        if (row.Id == cachedRowWithChanges.Id) { //example
            row.set("CartTotal", cachedRowWithChanges.CartTotal);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move your logic to change event of datasource

```
 dataSource: {        
    change: function(e) {
         // data will have new data source
         var data = this.data();    
    }  
 }
```

http://jsbin.com/saqaxefezo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

To prevent an infinite recursion, you can use a simple global variable or a custom property in the grid like this:

```js
function() {
    if (!this.__busy) {
        this.__busy = true;

        var pageData = grid.dataSource.data();
        $.each(pageData, function(index, row){
            if (row.Id == cachedRowWithChanges.Id) { //example
                row.set("CartTotal", cachedRowWithChanges.CartTotal);
            }
        });

        this.__busy = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a data item value via `set()` triggers the `change` event of the Grid DataSource instance, which in turn causes the Grid to rebind and display the latest state of its data.

What you can do to prevent multiple `dataBound` event firing is:

- use the `dataBinding` event instead
- update the data items via direct setters, not via the API:

  ```
  row.CartTotal = cachedRowWithChanges.CartTotal;
  row.dirty = true;
  ```
- the second line above is needed if you want to persist the changes to the remote data service via the built-in Kendo UI CRUD operations.

Here is an example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/AYOrIL

Comment: If I use dataBinding the sets inside the function repeatedly call dataBinding thus making that suggestion equivalent to dataBound.

Comment: If I don't use .set the data displayed doesn't get updated.